# Reading a certain number of bytes from standard input and then closing the pipe

Tags: command-line, pipe

I’m trying to read some bytes out of /dev/urandom, keep only the ones I can type easily, and trim the result to 30 characters. I can’t figure out how to get the “only 30 characters” behavior when the data is coming from a pipe, though. I tried

```
cat /dev/urandom | tr -cd 'A-Za-z0-9' | cut -c -30
```

and

```
cut -c -30 /dev/urandom | tr -cd 'A-Za-z0-9' | cut -c -30
```

but these hang without displaying anything. On the other hand,

```
cut -c -30 /dev/urandom | tr -cd 'A-Za-z0-9'
```

outputs data endlessly (although it’s clearly been processed by `tr` because only the specified characters appear in the output).

In general, how can I read a certain number of characters (or bytes) from a pipe and then close the pipe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cut` will read the input until end-of-file, and cut a part out of each line. With the two first commands, you don't see anything, since `tr` removes any newlines, and so `cut` never sees a full line to process. In the last, the `tr` again removes newlines so you don't see how nicely `cut`  kept the lines to a certain length.

Assuming your `head` utility supports the `-c <characters>` option, you could use it to get a fixed number of bytes. If it doesn't, use `dd`. (`dd bs=1 count=NNN < /dev/urandom`)

So, this would produce 32 alphanumerics (and a trailing newline):

```
tr -cd 'A-Za-z0-9' < /dev/urandom | head -c32 ; echo
```

Though, just out of principle, that's a bit of a waste since the `tr` tosses away about 3/4 or the raw input bytes. It might be better to pass the raw data from `urandom` to something like `base64` or anything that produces a hex dump.

Answer (score 0):

One simple way to make anything into readable characters:

```
$ head -c30 /dev/urandom | base64
nkGmuXgY/1OfNz8i/t3MsVe/5Q0z18AKotV3oJRW
```